# What is FLOPS in field of deep learning?

Tags: performance, deep-learning, flops

What is FLOPS in field of deep learning? Why we don't use the term just FLO?

We use the term FLOPS to measure the number of operations of a frozen deep learning network.

Following Wikipedia, FLOPS = floating point operations per second. When we test computing units, we should consider of the time. But in case of measuring deep learning network, how can I understand this concept of time? Shouldn't we use the term just FLO(floating point operations)?

Why do people use the term FLOPS? If there is anything I don't know, what is it?

==== attachment ===

Frozen deep learning networks that I mentioned is just a kind of software. It's not about hardware. In the field of deep learning, people use the term FLOPS to measure how many operations are needed to run the network model. In this case, in my opinion, we should use the term FLO. I thought people confused about the term FLOPS and I want to know if others think the same or if I'm wrong.

Please look at these cases:

[how to calculate a net's FLOPs in CNN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490555/how-to-calculate-a-nets-flops-in-cnn)

https://iq.opengenus.org/floating-point-operations-per-second-flops-of-machine-learning-models/

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I not sure my answer is 100% correct. but this is what i understand.

- FLOPS = **Fl**oating point **op**erations per **s**econd
- FLOPs = **Fl**oating point **op**eration**s**

FLOPS is a unit of speed. FLOPs is a unit of amount.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think you answered correctly, but I can't understand why people press down button.

Comment: So the higher FLOPS is the better(quicker) and the lower the FLOPs is the better(less operations). right?

Comment: @Franva Yes indeed.

Answer (score 74):

Confusingly both FLOP**s**, floating point operations, and FLOP**S**, floating point operations per second, are used in reference to machine learning. FLOPs are often used to describe how many operations are required to run a single instance of a given model, like VGG19. This is the usage of FLOPs in both of the links you posted, though unfortunately the opengenus link incorrectly mistakenly uses 'Floating point operations per second' to refer to FLOPs.

You will see FLOPS used to describe the computing power of given hardware like GPUs which is useful when thinking about how powerful a given piece of hardware is, or conversely, how long it may take to train a model on that hardware.

Sometimes people write FLOPS when they mean FLOPs. It is usually clear from the context which one they mean.

Comment: It is too late, but I want to say thank you for your kind answer.

Answer (score 8):

> What is FLOPS in field of deep learning? Why we don't use the term just FLO?

FLOPS (Floating Point Operations Per Second) is the same in most fields - its the (theoretical) maximum number of floating point operations that the hardware might (if you're extremely lucky) be capable of.

We don't use FLO because FLO would always be infinity (given an infinite amount of time hardware is capable of doing an infinite amount of floating point operations).

Note that one "floating point operation" is one multiplication, one division, one addition, ... Typically (for modern CPUs) FLOPS is calculated from repeated use of a "fused multiply then add" instruction, so that one instruction counts as 2 floating point operations. When combined with SIMD a single instruction (doing 8 "multiple and add" in parallel) might count as 16 floating point instructions. Of course this is a calculated theoretical value, so you ignore things like memory accesses, branches, IRQs, etc. This is why "theoretical FLOPs" is almost never achievable in practice.

> Why do people use the term FLOPS? If there is anything I don't know, what is it?

Primarily it's used to describe how powerful hardware is for marketing purposes (e.g. "Our new CPU is capable of 5 GFLOPS!").

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Sorry I couldn't fully understand what you said about instructions, because of my poor background of the field of hardware, but I agree what you are going to explain about the term of FLOPS. But.... you may miss my question, so I added some sentences to clear it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Why some models have higher FLOPs than others? Is it because we run on a better GPU only?

Comment: @Avv: In general, you'd increase "theoretical max. FLOPS" by being able to do more floating operations in parallel (e.g. wider SIMD doing 16 operations in parallel instead of 8 operations in parallel), or by doing each floating point operation faster (e.g. higher clock rate). Of course "higher theoretical max. FLOPS" can be "slower performance in practice" and can easily be "worse performance per watt". Ironically; if you design a large supercomputer around "How much performance can we get out of 1234 MW" you end up with a huge number of slow/efficient nodes..