calculating Flops of the model
@al2
I am using the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63426284/25649468 to calculate the flops. I have my_model.h5 file. I am getting the huge difference in the flops calculations. When the other author mentioned number of flops in their paper for the X model and when I am using the same X model. Is it possible to have the difference(large)?
If yes, why is the difference?
Thanks to @al2 for the code
import tensorflow as tf

def get_flops(model_h5_path):
    session = tf.compat.v1.Session()
    graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
        

    with graph.as_default():
        with session.as_default():
            model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model_h5_path)

            run_meta = tf.compat.v1.RunMetadata()
            opts = tf.compat.v1.profiler.ProfileOptionBuilder.float_operation()
        
            # We use the Keras session graph in the call to the profiler.
            flops = tf.compat.v1.profiler.profile(graph=graph,
                                                  run_meta=run_meta, cmd='op', options=opts)
        
            return flops.total_float_ops

model.save('path_to_my_model.h5')
tf.compat.v1.reset_default_graph()
print(get_flops('path_to_my_model.h5'))

