# Counting the number of multiply-add operations (MAC) in Caffe CNN's architecture

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network, flops

Lately I've been benchmarking some CNNs regarding time, # of multiply-add operations (MAC), # of parameters and model size. I have seen some similar SO questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996593/is-it-possible-in-caffe-to-calculate-number-of-operations-taking-place-in-an-arc) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43490555/how-to-calculate-a-nets-flops-in-cnn/43491707#43491707)) and in the latter, they suggest using [Netscope CNN Analyzer](https://dgschwend.github.io/netscope/quickstart.html). This tool allows me to calculate most of the things I need just by inputing my Caffe network definition.

However, the number of multiply-add operations of some architectures I've seen in papers and over the internet doesn't match what Netscope is outputting, whereas other architectures match. I'm always comparing either FLOPs or MAC with the MACC column in netscope, but there a ~10x factor that I'm forgetting at some point (check table bellow for more detail).

```
Architecture  ----  MAC (paper/internet) ---- macc column in netscope
VGG 16                    ~15.5G                       ~157G
GoogLeNet                 ~1.55G                       ~16G
```

Reference about [GoogLeNet macc number](https://dgschwend.github.io/netscope/#/preset/googlenet) and [VGG16 macc number](https://dgschwend.github.io/netscope/#/preset/vgg-16) in Netscope.

Does anybody that used that tool could point me out on what mistake I'm doing while reading Netscope output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found what was causing the discrepancy between Netscope and the information I'd found in papers. Most preset architectures in Nestcope were using a batch size of 10 (this is the case for [VGG](https://dgschwend.github.io/netscope/#/preset/vgg-16) and [GoogLeNet](https://dgschwend.github.io/netscope/#/preset/googlenet), for example), therefore the x10 factor that multiplied the number of mult-add operations.